# How can I force Localization Culture to en-US for whole applicaiton in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How to force **Xamain - Android / iOS** to work in **US English** culture regardless of user setting.
The issue I am facing in my application is, The app only support US/UK English, But if the user changes the langue preference to  Spanish , German etc. The number date etc format will change.

For Example,
**2.35** will represent in Spanish, German as **2,35**.

So if the user try to use the application with similar language, the app will miss behave or crash. Crash will occur in situation like when I try for `Convert.ToDouble("2,35");` or similar.

So my doubt is,

Is it possible in Xamarin to **forcefully set the culture as en-US**. May be in one place, otherwise I need to change it all the places I performing Conversion.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set current culture in your app. Localisation works really well. This is how I did it:

```
public void SetLocale(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

    }
```

And here you get the culture from device:

```
public CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo()
    {
        var netLanguage = "en";
        if (NSLocale.PreferredLanguages.Length > 0)
        {
            var pref = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages[0];

            netLanguage = iOSToDotnetLanguage(pref);
        }

        // this gets called a lot - try/catch can be expensive so consider caching or something
        CultureInfo ci = null;
        try
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(netLanguage);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException e1)
        {
        }
     }
private string iOSToDotnetLanguage(string iOSLanguage)
    {
     // Testing special cases..
    }
```

If you use PCL project, use abstraction. Use interface in PCL and its implementation in native project.

You can see more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/localization

Comment: Is it enough to set this once in App.CS or should i set local in every viewModel or code behind?

Comment: @Ali123 sorry I see comment accidentally now, quote my name next time, so I get a notification. It's enough to do it only once when you're starting your app, initializing it that is. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 19):

I am working with a `Xamarin Forms` App.

Setting the Culture in the `App` Class did the trick for me.

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;


private void SetCultureToUSEnglish()
{
    CultureInfo englishUSCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = englishUSCulture;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default culture with following property:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture
```

But this won't work in Android. So for Android you need to set the culture every time an activity gets resumed. You can add a base activity like:

```
internal class MyBaseActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        // Here you would read it from where ever.
        var userSelectedCulture = new CultureInfo ("fr-FR");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = userSelectedCulture;
    }
}
```

Found in the xamarin forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9764/how-to-set-a-global-cultureinfo-for-an-app

Answer (score 5):

I try Joehl approach but it didn't work for me. I used this approach

```
        string cultureName = "es-US";
        var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(cultureName);
        Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;

        var config = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration { Locale = locale };
        BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(config, BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
```

Also created a base activity

Find answer here:

[changing cultureinfo on android using xamarin and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215964/changing-cultureinfo-on-android-using-xamarin-and-c-sharp)

Comment: UpdateConfiguration seems to be deprecated. what is a good alternative for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Localize` class with the translate extension and lang resources are all set, you can call the `setLocale` method at runtime available in each platform projects from PCL using the interface `ILocalize` like this:

```
CultureInfo ci=new CultureInfo("en-US");
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().SetLocale(ci);                      
AppResources.Culture = ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a combination of the other answers!

Basically, I didn't find the need to create a new Activity and extend it as suggested. Instead, I added the following override into MainActivity.cs:

```
  protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            try
            {
                var userSelectedCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = userSelectedCulture;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

and then, inside OnCreate, I added the following:

```
  try
            {
                string cultureName = "en-GB";
                var locale = new Java.Util.Locale(cultureName);
                Java.Util.Locale.Default = locale;

                var configg = new Android.Content.Res.Configuration { Locale = locale };
                BaseContext.Resources.UpdateConfiguration(configg, BaseContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }
```

I tested it inside an emulator by changing the language to French and showing a simple DateTime to find out whether today displays as samedi or Saturday and it displayed Saturday!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms App and I have the same requirement, I have ended up using the [**MultilingualPlugin**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin) for Xamarin.Forms

Comment: MultilingualPlugin is deprecated and no longer supported ...so save yourself a link click